# BigBlueButton/Greenlight: 502 Bad Gateway Error

Tags: bigbluebutton, http-status-code-502

I have running Bugbluebutton with Greenlight in my private **VPS**. By the installation everything worked perfectly with no errors while the installation. After an Update I get permamently the Error Code *502 "Bad Gateway"* by accessing the Server.

[image: 502 error Picture]

Here is the `bbb-conf --status` output:

[image: bbb-conf --status output]

Here is the `bbb-conf --check` output:

[image: bbb-conf --check output Part 1]
[image: bbb-conf --check output Part 2]

I dont know how to troubleshooting this error. I have looked on the BBB-Troubleshooting Guide and on Github, but I have found nothing that worked for me. When more log Files needed please tell me.

Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not found the Problem, but afer update greenlight to the newest version the Error disappears

Answer (score 0):

please enter this command with SSH;

```
docker-compose up -d

docker exec -it greenlight-v3 bundle exec rake admin:create['Your Name','email@example.com','!Example11Password']
```